# Perform actions on slider as per the given value

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an amount slider that can take value from 0 to 100,000.

I want to move the slider as per the amount given. For example if the amount given is 20,000 slider should move 20,000.

```
        WebElement slider2 = driver.findElement(By.id("ex2Slider"));
        Actions move = new Actions(driver);
        action.clickAndHold(slider2);
        action.moveByOffset(320, 0).build().perform();
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: provide a html sample (not a screenshot), for sure there should have tag with something lie  data-min data-max, data-current.